# Spatial Join operation on geography Points in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have `Geography` points in my table named `Route`. Let me explain what I am trying to do.

There are two types of routes, `ConstructionPlanning` (`LayerId=4`) and `ConstructionHistory` (`LayerId=1`).

`LayerId` is a column in the `Route` table which denotes if the `Route` is a `ConstructionPlanning` or `ConstructionHistory` route. Now I am saving all the Routes in that table and the attached `LayerId` with it. I have the below function which helps me to find if a `ConstructionPlanning` exists for a `ConstructionHistory` which I am doing using Spatial Join. The parameter value being passed into this function `@RouteId` belongs to `LayerId=1`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetPlannedProjectId]
(
    @RouteId int
)
RETURNS INT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @finalresult INT
    DECLARE @result TABLE (id INT,PlanningType INT,
                           PlannedYear INT,
                           starting sys.geography, 
                           ending sys.geography,
                           chachedroute sys.geography)
    
    DECLARE @tablevar TABLE(id INT,ProjectType INT,PlannedYear INT)

    INSERT INTO @result 
        SELECT 
            id,
            (SELECT Type FROM CP_ProjectInfo 
             WHERE ConsPlanningId = (SELECT id FROM ConstructionPlanning 
                                     WHERE RouteId = R.Id)),
            (SELECT PlannedYear FROM CP_ProjectInfo 
             WHERE ConsPlanningId = (SELECT id FROM ConstructionPlanning 
                                     WHERE RouteId = R.Id)),
            starting, Ending, CachedRoute 
        FROM 
            Route R 
        WHERE
            LayerId = 4 
            AND CachedRoute.STDistance((SELECT CachedRoute FROM route 
                                        WHERE id = @RouteId)) < 0.5 
    
    insert into @tablevar 
    select id,PlanningType,PlannedYear from @result where
          chachedroute.STDistance((select starting from route where id=@RouteId))<700 and 
                 chachedroute.STDistance((select ending from route where id=@RouteId))<700
    intersect
    select id,PlanningType,PlannedYear from @result     
    select @finalresult=id from @tablevar
    RETURN ISNULL(@finalresult,0)
END
```

So I call the above function as

```
select dbo.GetPlannedProjectId(12451)
select dbo.GetPlannedProjectId(12452)
select dbo.GetPlannedProjectId(12453)
```

Output:

```
25834
```

Now the above output is correct.
Similarly I want a function similar to the one mentioned here. But the function I want will have the input `25384` and the outputs will be

```
12451
12452
12453
```

Its just the way reversed of the previous function. I kept everything same and just changed the `LayerId` value to `LayerId=1` in my other function since the mentioned function has `LayerId=4` but somehow I am not able to achieve it. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The below is the function which helps to get the `ConstructionHistory` for a passed `ConstructionPlanning` value. The below function returns single or multiple values.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSegmentId]
(   
    @Planningid INT,
    @agencyID int
)

RETURNS @tablevar TABLE 
(
    id INT
)

AS

BEGIN
        declare    @CachedRoute geography
        DECLARE @finalresult int
        DECLARE @result TABLE (id INT, starting sys.geography, ending sys.geography,chachedroute sys.geography)
        

        set @CachedRoute = (select CachedRoute from route where id = @Planningid)

        insert into @result select id,
        starting,Ending,CachedRoute from Route R where AgencyId=@agencyID and LayerId=1 and CachedRoute.STDistance(@CachedRoute)<0.5 

        insert into @tablevar
        select id from @result where @CachedRoute.STDistance(starting)<700 and @CachedRoute.STDistance(ending)<700
        intersect
        select id from @result


    RETURN;
END;
```